# How to fix 'Please run rails webpacker: install Error: No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am attempting to create my first Ruby on Rails application following the documentation outlined on the website. When I attempted to run the server with 'rails server' from the cmd line I receive this error...

```
C:/Ruby/rubyinstaller-2.5.5-1-x64/rubyinstaller-2.5.5-1-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/webpacker-4.0.7/lib/webpacker/configuration.rb:91:in `rescue in load': Webpacker configuration file not found C:/Users/{username}/Desktop/Projects/Ruby on Rails/Blog Application/blog/config/webpacker.yml. Please run rails webpacker:install Error: No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - C:/Users/{username}/Desktop/Projects/Ruby on Rails/Blog Application/blog/config/webpacker.yml
```

OS: Windows 10 
Yarn version: 1.17.3 
Node.js version - v10.15.3 
Rails version - 6.0.0 
Ruby version - Ruby 2.5.5p157 (2019-03-15 revision 67260) [x64-mingw32]
sqlite3 version - 3.22.0

I expect for the server to run successfully and to open localhost:3000 to Yay! You're on rails

Comment: The error message tells you what to do, in your terminal run: `rails webpacker:install`

Comment: Doesn't work $ rails webpacker:install

Comment: I closed the current instance of my terminal and then tried `rails webpacker:install` and was prompted to install Yarn. After installing Yarn, I was then able to install `rails webpacker:install`

Answer (score 32):

You may want to install `yarn` and then recreate your application if `rails webpacker:install` doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I bit late, hopefully it helps someone using Linux:

Run:

```
bundle exec rails webpacker:install
```

That should fix the issue but in case you get the following the error:

> superclass mismatch for class Command (TypeError)

run:

```
sudo dpkg -r --force-depends ruby-thor

sudo gem install thor
```

And then run again:

```
 bundle exec rails webpacker:install
```